# posting additional data in edit mode of jquery jqgrid and custom validations for inline editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Im using jqgrid wherein i need to pass addtional data to the controller while editing... but i m not able to do so... here is my code below..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

//

```
        var checkMileageLimit = function (value, colname) {

            var clName = (colname == 'MileageLimitPM' ? 'MileageLimitAM' : 'MileageLimitPM');

            if (parseInt(value) + parseInt($('#' + clName).val()) > parseInt($("#TotalMileage").val())) {
                return [false, "sum of AM and PM mileage should not  exceed Total Mileage", ""];
            }
            else return [true, "", ""];
        };

        var checkTouchLimit = function (value, colname) {

            var clName = (colname == 'TouchLimitPM' ? 'TouchLimitAM' : 'TouchLimitPM');

            if (parseInt(value) + parseInt($('#' + clName).val()) > parseInt($("#TotalTouches").val())) {
                return [false, "sum of AM and PM Touches should not  exceed Total Touches", ""];
            }
            else return [true, "", ""];
        };

        var lastsel;
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("GetScheduleInfo", "TouchSchedule") %>',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            postData: {
                StartDate: function () { return $('#StartDate').val(); },
                EndDate: function () { return $('#EndDate').val(); },
                siteId: function () { return $('#ListFacility').length == 0 ? -1 : $('#ListFacility').val(); }
            },
            colNames: ['RowID', 'SiteID', 'CalDate', 'Store Open', 'Start Time', 'End Time',
                   'MileageLimit AM', 'MileageLimit PM', 'TouchLimit PM',
                   'TouchLimit AM', 'Total Touches', 'Total Mileage', 'WeekDay'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'RowID', index: 'RowID', width: 40, key: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidedlg: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'SiteID', index: 'SiteID', width: 40, /* key: true,*/editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidedlg: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'CalDate', index: 'CalDate', width: 100, formatter: 'date', datefmt: 'm/d/Y', editable: false, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'StoreOpen', index: 'StoreOpen', width: 40, editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' }, editoptions: { value: { o: 'Open', c: 'closed'} }, width: "40" },
            { name: 'StartTime', index: 'StartTime', width: 100, editable: true, formatter: 'date', masks: 'ShortTime', edittype: 'text', editrules: { time: true, required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'EndTime', index: 'EndTime', width: 100, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { time: true, required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'MileageLimitAM', index: 'MileageLimitAM', width: 50, editable: true, formatter: 'integer',
                edittype: 'text', editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: checkMileageLimit,
                    required: true
                }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' }
            },
            { name: 'MileageLimitPM', index: 'MileageLimitPM', width: 50, editable: true, edittype: 'text', formatter: 'integer', editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: checkMileageLimit, required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'TouchLimitAM', index: 'TouchLimitAM', width: 50, editable: true, edittype: 'text', formatter: 'integer', editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: checkTouchLimit, required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'TouchLimitPM', index: 'TouchLimitPM', width: 50, editable: true, edittype: 'text', formatter: 'integer', editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: checkTouchLimit, required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'TotalTouches', index: 'TotalTouches', width: 50, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'TotalMileage', index: 'TotalMileage', width: 50, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
            { name: 'WeekDay', index: 'WeekDay', width: 200, editable: false, hidden: false }
        ],
            pager: $('#listPager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: 'CalDate',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Schedule Calendar',
            autowidth: false,
            gridview: true,
            id: "RowID",    

            ondblClickRow: function (id) {

                if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editGridRow', id,{ onclickSubmit});
                    lastsel = id;
                }

            }
          , editurl: '<%= Url.Action("UpdateGrid", "TouchSchedule") %>'

        }).navGrid('#listPager',
               { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true },
                 {width:400,height:400,closeAfterEdit:true,
                onclickSubmit:function(params) {   var ajaxData = {};

                var list = $("#list");
                var selectedRow = list.getGridParam("selrow");
                rowData = list.getRowData(selectedRow);
                ajaxData = { CalDate: rowData.CalDate };

                return ajaxData; }}

    );

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $("#list").clearGridData();
            $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");

        });
    });
```

//]]>

Please let me know where i m going wrong... also i have observed that if i use inline editing then the custom validation is not being fired? how to solve this problem via inline editing?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you don't use inline editing at all in your code. You use `editGridRow` and in a wrong way:

```
jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editGridRow', id,{ onclickSubmit});
```

instead of the usage of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) used in the inline editing mode.

You should at least set a value for the onclickSubmit event handle:

```
jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editGridRow', id,
                       { onclickSubmit : function(params, posdata) {
                                             alert ("in onclickSubmit");
                                             // ...
                                         }
                       });
```

Moreover you try to use validation based not on the `value` parameter which you receive as a parameter of the custom validation function. You try to read another text fields. You should understand, that it is not the best way. Moreover in case of inline editing the text fields will nave the ids not like the corresponding names of the columns. So the usage of `$("#TotalMileage")` will be OK for the form editing, but it should be `$("#"+rowid+"_TotalMileage")` in case of inline editing.

You can consider to use [beforeCheckValues](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) function additionally which will get use all fields of the data which will be posted. The function will be called **before** verifying of every field of the form. In case of inline editing this is not possible, so you will have to detect in any way the mode which you use (for example you can set a variable which define the current manually) and use the corresponding name conversion of the field ids. Another way is the usage of [dataEvents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) with for example `'change'` event handler.

To send additional data in case of form editing you can use `editData`, return the object with the additional data from `onclickSubmit` or you custom `serializeEditData` function. You can also modify the url used during data posting inside of the `onclickSubmit` function.

To send additional data in inline editing mode you can use `extraparam` parameter of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) or use [inlineData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) parameter of the jqGrid.

One more remark at the end. You should start to use [voting up](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) of your answers and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answers. At least you have comment another answer and post additional information needed to answer on your questions. For example some time ago you asked already [almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144016/custom-validation-for-jqgrid) and I asked you to post HTML code. Many other your questions stay uncommented and it is not clear whether you at least read there. It so will be continued you will be receive less or no answers at all.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions again.. i will vote up and i have already marked your suggestion as correct answer for my previous post...i was not aware of voting and now i will be sure about updating it...i was not satisfied with the earlier answers i got for my other posts so i left them un-commented,i will update them also.. but,For the current question i have managed to do edits via form dialog and now the requirement has changed to inline edit and  multiple edits on a single click..i will review ur suggestion and will implement it and will get back to you..thank you again :)

Comment: @Rakesh: You welcome! I don't recommend you to try multi row edits. It will makes all too complex especially if you think about multi-user environment and possible errors in one from the many editable rows. How could be an error message in the case? It can be that many changes done by the user need be done one more time. I personally like inline editing more as form editing, but if you save the data on the server, then the last check of data must be done on the server side and you should make tests with errors send from the server side.

Comment: hi, yes u r right.. but the client demands a multi select.. the editing will be over a collection of rows which will have the same data except the date will be different.. maybe i have the user to select the rows.. and via jqgrid i will have rowids .. i have to take them to a diff screen where i have the textboxes and do a update.. and as u have said everything has to be managed server side only....i have somehow managed form edit..but yet to understand inline edit and custom validations for it

Answer (score 0):

At a glance I would say it has something to do with that you are using a GET and not a POST. Get will concatenate the data onto the query string. This might be interfering with the grid.